# Find and disable unwanted form validation

Tags: html, forms, validation

I have this input `<input class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" id="namePatient" name="name_patient" type="text" required autocomplete="off">`

I added the 'required' property to use with jquery.validation, but when i submit this form, there is already a validation occurring. But I cant find its origin.

Just for adding the property `required` now the form does a validation that returns like this:
[image: sample image]

I need to know where does this validation come from and how to disable it, so it wont override jquery.validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable HTML5 default validation, add `novalidate` to the form

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp